# Why’s the graph of xy and yz appear same on Geogebra 3D?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, 3d

I drew the graphs of $f(x,y)=xy$ and $g(y,z)=yz$ on Geogebra $3 \text{D}$ and I found both of them similar. How is this the case? How are the two graphs $(x,y,xy)$ and $(yz,y,z)$ similar?

For example: $f(2,3) = 6$ gives the point $(2,3,6)$ but $g(3,6) \neq 2$.

So how exactly is the function plotted? I don’t think it’s in the way I assumed.

Comment: I don't know how Geogebra works, but IIRC: Mathematically, the symbols $x$, $y$, and $z$ have no absolute meaning, so the specifications $f$ and $g$ are literally identical: Each says _function value of first variable, second variable is first times second_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geogebra doesn't know that your $y$ and $z$ carry special meanings.

It just interpreted $y$ as the first input and map it to $x$ and $z$ as the second input and map it to $y$.

You might like to plot $z=xy$ and $x=yz$ explicitly.